# Is it possible to open a website when clicking vbMsgHelpButton?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a MsgBox that displays both "OK" and "Help" buttons. I would like to redirect to a website when Help button is clicked, but I'm completely unable to achieve it.
I have read in some forums that the easiest way to get it is to make your own userform and to assign a subroutine to each button attached.
Another possible way that I've found is to create a *.hlp file, call it from the Help File parameter and place the proper context ID, but I need to store the help file in a website, and, anyway, I can't find the context IDs numbers.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you would need to put in the VBE for your help button.

```
Private Sub HelpButton_Click()
Dim IE as Object

Set IE = CreateObject(InternetExplorer.Application)

IE.Visible = True

IE.Navigate = "Insert your URL here"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/excel-vba/automate-internet-explorer/)  you can find all you need to manage URLs to be opened with Internet Explorer (easiest way) .
In the link I gave it will be shown how to use IE (Internet Explorer) libraries in order to manage some tasks such as opening URL (which you can of course trigger by a click on the "help" button in your userform), filling forms and/or click buttons in a webpage.
Although I think if you have directly a help web page, the first option will suffice. 
An overview of what can help you in the link I gave you:

```
Sub GoToWebSite()
Dim appIE As Object ' InternetExplorer
Dim sURL As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set appIE = GetIE

sURL = "yourhelpwebpage"

' Here you can add the "on Help button click" action to trigger the following
With appIE
    .Navigate sURL
    .Visible = True
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set appIE = Nothing
End Sub
```